# Center TextView on ImageButton Programmatically

Tags: android

I need to set `TextView` centered on a `ImageButton`, but using code. I can set a text on, but I can't center it.

**code:**

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);            

TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("text");
textView.setTextSize(25);            
textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

final ImageButton iButton = new ImageButton(this);
iButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
iButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

rLayout.addView(iButton);
rLayout.addView(textView);
linear.addView(rLayout);
```

This code set text on imageButton, but set it in left-top.

Comment: Why don't you use Button with text and background image instead of ImageButton and TextView?

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of unclear what you're asking...but if I'm understanding correctly, you have to set the [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) on the TextView before adding it to the parent.  Also, you have to add the rule RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT.

So, something like:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(size, size)
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT)
textView.setLayoutParams(params)
```

Or some other combination of rules that fit your usecase.

Comment: I only need put a text centered on imageButton.

Answer (score 1):

so try

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
params.weight = 1.0f;
params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

iButton.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Cannot setGravity in ibutton

Comment: Desn't work. Set lot of distance beetween text and button.

Comment: try to reduce your text size from 25 to 16